# How to execute a test just after another test has been executed?

Tags: java, testng, integration-testing

I need to execute a testNG test method (`testA`) just after another test method(`testB`) has been executed. Also I want to annotate testA with `@Test` because I want to tell testNG that it is a test method not a configuration method.

I was able to do with `@AfterMethod` but testNG was treating testA as a configuration method which I don't want it to.

Also I need to execute testA just after testB has been executed. I don't want another test to run in between. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
@Test (dependsOnMethods={"methodB"})
public void methodA () {

 }
```

See also 
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods

Comment: what if now I have another test testC and just after testC is executed also I need to execute testA?

Comment: think you could name both methodB and methodC in dependaOnMethods ... can't try it out atm though... more general advice: don't do this if you don't have too, usually atomic testcases are preferable...

Comment: ok thanks for the advise.. bdw is testC guaranteed to be executed just after testB? i mean with dependsOnMethods option?

Comment: Sorry not sure about that, docs don't state that explicitly, guess you'll have to try it out